# Merge репозиторий (6)

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Всем привет
Трудно быть начинающим в сфере IT, по этому решил обратиться за помощью так как отстаю от своего обучения.

На Git у меня 6 разных репозиторий
В процессе пропустил детали гита и теперь страдаю, так как нужен только один репозиторий и все.

Помогите разобраться как сделать merge всех репозиторий в один и при этом что бы я мог сохранить все изменения с самого старта, что бы видеть как мой проект менялся все это время.

Заранее всем спасибо !!!

[image: Фото всех репозиторий с гита]

Remote - у меня сейчас самый первый репозиторий git-test.

Comment: [How to merge two repositories on git?](https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-merge-two-repositories-on-git-b0ed5e3b4448)

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: На скриншоте у вас что-то похожее на gitlab/github, а значит там есть механизм создания репозиторев fork'ами. Использовался он, или это полностью независимые репозитории?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов на гитхабе было бы написано "Forked from ...", на гитлабе другой UI

Answer (score 2):

Это уже обсуждалось, ответ здесь [git merge different repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949738/git-merge-different-repositories).
Если кратко на русском, то будет примерно так.

Чтобы влить коммиты проекта A в проект B, нужно:

1. перейти в проект B, перейти на ветку, в которую будем вливать проект A:

   ```
   cd путь_к_репозиторию_B
   git checkout имя_нужной_ветки_в_репозитории_B
   ```
2. для удобства задаем ссылку на репозиторий А. Имя лучше взять отличное от общепринятого origin, чтобы потом было понятно, из какого проекта мы влили коммиты:

   ```
   git remote add имя_ссылки_на_репозиторий_А ссылка_на_репозиторий_А
   ```
3. и мержим:

   получаем изменения с репозитория А:

   ```
   git fetch имя_ссылки_на_репозиторий_А 

   git merge --allow-unrelated-histories имя_ссылки_на_репозиторий_А/имя_ветки_репозитория_А
   ```
4. Удаляем ссылку на репозиторий А:

   ```
   git remote remove имя_ссылки_на_репозиторий_А
   ```

Опцию `--allow-unrelated-histories` можно не использовать начиная с версии гита 2.9. Узнать версию гита можно так:

```
git --version
```

Comment: Благодарю, помогло )